# Is it possible to drag windows not from their title like holding ALT in Unity?

Tags: window-management, pantheon

I have Pantheon installed on Ubuntu if it matters..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, however not with the Alt (Hyper) but the Windows (Super) key held down.